# clicking messagebox.show() hides showdialog() window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following code in WPF:

```
 private void BtnTicketPrice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TicketPrice TP = new TicketPrice();
        TP.ShowDialog();
    }
```

in New Window form i have following code:

```
private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

        {
                MessageBox.Show("sometext");
        }
```

on clicking messagebox button the form (`TicketPrice`) also is closing;
how to show messagebox without closing the form?

If i'd change `TP.ShowDialog();` to `TP.Show();`, it works correctly. I have this problem only with this TP.ShowDialog();

xaml of button

```
    <Button x:Name="BtnSave" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="619,362,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Height="66" IsCancel="True" TabIndex="4" Click="BtnSave_Click"> 
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
<TextBlock Text="save " HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" /> 
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Save.png" Height="50" Width="59" /> 
</StackPanel> 
</Button>
```

Comment: How are we supposed to guess what's wrong with your code if you won't show it to us?

Comment: You need to show the XAML for BtnSave too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the `IsCancel` property on the `Button` working as advertised. Don't set it to `true` and clicking the button won't automatically close the dialog.

Comment: thanks. it works. This is the result of fatigue )))) thanks